# writing json string to xls file using python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, xls

I am trying to parse one json string to excel file. But facing some errors

```
import pandas
...
...
response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)
#print(response.text)
df_json = json.loads(response.text)
print(df_json) -- this is printing json as string
df = pd.read_json(df_json)
-- now i want to load this into excel
df.to_excel('c:\scripts\DATAFILE.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

can some one help please

Comment: Can you please share the result of your print(df_json)

Comment: it's more normal to use `response.json()` to get the JSON rather than text.  This assumes MIME types are set correctly.   Share output of `print(df_json)` so help can be provided with your actual issue

Comment: I guess my json output it self messy, not able to parse..need to figure out

Comment: the error is obvious, you don't have a dataframe but a dictionary. please share a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.read_json()` takes a file path or a JSON string as input. You should check the type of `df_json` because `json.loads()` deserializes the input.
If it is a dict you could simply do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_json)
```

If it's a list it's a bit more complex.

Also I would refrain from prefixing variable names "df" if they aren't dataframes.